# Timer_ConnectionIdle IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I get **Timer_ConnectionIdle** message from error logs of httperror folder in system32/logfiles.

And sometimes the web page return service unavailable or connection refused.

What is the problem?

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two Different issues that you are talking about.

Timer connection idle is not something you need to be worried about. It is HTTP.SYS's way of telling you that the client with which it established a connection did not disconnect because there is always a chance that the client would want to establish the connection again. I think it usually waits for 2 minutes before terminating the connection and that is when you get this message in the HTTPERR logs.

Now coming to Service Unavailable and Connection Timeout errors, this is something that you need to take note of. Check for event logs during the time of issue and see if you find anything there.

If you are unable to find anything in the event logs, my next question would be to identify what is done in order to overcome the issue ? Do you recycle the application pool to get the application up and running ? Do you reset IIS ? If you do any of the above, then please capture a full user dump of w3wp process using debug diag during the time of issue (before performing an iisreset or application pool recycle). Analyzing the dump will tell you exactly whats going wrong.

Feel free to follow up with any questions you have.

Comment: With using debug I get `System.Web.HttpException on thread`  error in log.
I don't know why that occurs and totally what I must be do?

Comment: share complete exception details please !!

Comment: The txt file of debug diag will not tell you what went wrong. Debug Diag generates a .dmp file. Please follow this article to capture the data - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debugdiag/2013/03/15/debug-diagnostic-1-2-generate-a-manual-hang-dump-on-a-specific-process/

Comment: This link is a capture from .dmp file : http://tstpl.mp4.ir/Files/crash.jpg

Comment: This isn't stating too much :( The part where it says that multiple asp.net requests are executing with same session ID could be due to multiple requests sent by the client when the application was hung. I can debug the dump file manually but for that you will have to share it with me. I understand you might have concerns around that so I would recommend you to open a support case with Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful guidances.
Yes in one of my web page I had a session that have same value for every users,and I optimize that and then my problem solved.

Comment: An another issue exists that cause of **Service Unavailable** in my web site,For recommending videos I hash video ids in a hidden input for every users and after video finished send it on url for calling next video, this is a queue for having relative videos and I see debug diag log it has **overflow exception** for this what I can do? increasing url length in iis can help me for my solution?

Comment: And I'm using viewstate for keep video ids as queue.Is it possible that overflow exception related to the size of viewstate?

Comment: Having a large viewstate will only slow down the performance of your application. You may have to apply some other business logic here